# Identifying boundaries of handlebodies to get 3-manifolds

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I am reading Prasolov & Sossinski's book : *Knots,Links, Braids and 3-manifolds* ([here](https://books.google.gr/books?id=9rOIAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=dehn%20lickorish%20theorem%20and%20corolaries&source=bl&ots=e1gHjKrRK3&sig=J9RqEVpc7i3GvNIAE-OZnlvlEFw&hl=el&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUl4reroraAhUnYZoKHUgvA1QQ6AEwAXoECAAQQg#v=onepage&q=dehn%20lickorish%20theorem%20and%20corolaries&f=false)) but I have trouble understanding how the identifications of handlebodies (solid tori with $g$ holes) work.

Let me give a concrete source of confusion:

At page $85$ , corollary $12.4$ (see the link) we want to prove the following:

Suppose that

- $X,X'$ are homeomoprhic (with homeomorphism $j_1:X\rightarrow X'$)
- $Y,Y'$ are homeomoprhic (with homeomorphism $j_2:Y\rightarrow Y'$)
- We get the manifold $Z$ by identifying $\partial X$ with $\partial Y$ along $f_0:\partial X \rightarrow \partial Y$

Then, connecting the boundaries of $\partial X',\partial Y'$ along $h=j_2f_0j_1^{-1}$ gives us $Z'$ which is homeomorphic to $Z$.

But! Say we have two homomorphisms from $\partial X$ to $\partial Y$ ,$f'$ yielding $Z'$ and $f''$ yielding $Z''$. By taking (as above) $j_1=f''f'^{-1}$ and $j_2=id$ then $h=id(f'(f'^{-1}f''))=f''$ so we have that identifying $X$ with $Y$ along $f''$ gives us also $Z'$. But that would mean that we cannot obtain different manifolds via different identifications, which is of course nonsense.

**The question:** What went wrong in the above argument?

**Attempt to answer:** I assumed that $f''f'^{-1}$ is homeomorphism from $X\rightarrow X'$ when in reality is from $X$ to itself.

We assume that all four Handlebodies have some specified curves on their boundary which dictate the needed homomorphism. Therefore while $X,X'$ are homeomorphic (indeed all four manifolds are) they may have a different system of curves specified on them (e.g. both may be solid tori but $X$ have a meridian specified and $X'$ may have a parallel specified) and so it is wrong to assume that $f''f'^{-1}$ is from $X$ to $X'$.

Comment: Aren't $f'$ and $f''$ maps on the boundary only? How are you extending to the whole manifold?

Comment: @SteveD If I understand correctly, when I take compositions of maps I restrict the $j_i$ at the boundary. Hopefully, you can see the passage I am referring to from the given link if there is something that I am not writing/understanding properly.

Comment: I cannot see the link, sorry.  But what you're suggesting cannot be right.  For example, we can glue two solid tori in two different ways: one way gives us $S^3$, the other gives us $S^2\times S^1$.  The gluing map (your $f_0$) is the only difference here. Taking $j_i$ to be the map that switches coordinates on the torus (in the universal cover, it is the map $(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$) allows us to go from one $f_0$ to the other.  So your claim would imply $S^3$ is homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^1$, which is absurd.  The problem here is that this $j_1$ map cannot be extended to the entire solid torus.

Comment: @SteveD I now see what you mean, and feel that you are correct. I will contemplate on it and see if I understand it. Thank you very much !